# Is the Volley API thread-safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-volley

In the Android Volley API I need to make some request object to be placed into a request queue and that object will receive the response.

Is this thread safe? If multiple threads try to access the queue and retrieve the result what happens?

Comment: Depends on the queue. Some queues are thread safe, some are not. I think your question needs more details, maybe a hypothetical situation to discuss.

Comment: @nmr I think he mean `RequestQueue` which is part of Volley library, I didn't find any other `Queue` there.

Comment: If so, then the question doesn't make sense to me. The request queue does not "receive the response". I thought maybe he meant another queue, to which responses were posted.

Comment: @nmr:Yes I mean the request queue. And from the examples I have seen the requests placed in the queue retrieve the results via the Request<T> methods

Answer (score 1):

The Volley API is thread safe. All responses are dispatched on the main thread, and any thread may queue requests. No idea what queue you're talking about though ;)

Comment: So if thread A and thread B call the same function that ends up adding 2 request objects in the queue how does each thread know which response belongs to the thread? From the examples I have seen in tutorials the response is processed by the object in the queue via the Request<T>.onResponse. So how will the onResponse code know that the response received is for that thread? I mean if you send request X and then request Y in the network you can get the response of Y before the response of X. Is this clearer now? Perhaps the fact that I am new to android does not help me express my confusion

Comment: In Volley terms, the responses do not "belong" to the threads "A" and "B". The responses are delivered to the instance of `Response.Listener` that you construct the request with, via the `#onResponse` method. This always happens on the main thread.

Comment: By main thread do you mean the main launched activity? But what if we launch background threads to fetch some data while the user is doing something else in the UI? In that case thread A would pass JSON requestA and thread B JSON request B as part of 2 separate request objects to the request queue. And the response listener when it is called would have to "know" how to process each response as it might be a different handling for each response and the response might return in different order. Is this not a valid scenario?

Comment: By main thread I mean the Android UI thread, which is the thread which calls `Activity#onCreate`, which I think is what you mean. Don't be mistaken, if you have two requests, "A" and "B", in order to distinguish their responses you should use two separate response listeners when you create the requests.